# Trouble importing an image

Tags: node.js, image, canvas, discord.js

I keep getting this error when importing an image and using canvas with discord.js:

```js
C:\Users\Travi\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\re\src\img\licenseTemp.png:1
�PNG


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Here's my code:
I'm also using module Alias so that's why it's  const licenseTemp = require('@img')

```js
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Canvas = require('canvas');
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const licenseTemp = require('@img');

module.exports = class RankCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('rank', 'Information', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(449, 292);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const background = await Canvas.loadImage(licenseTemp);
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    const attachment = new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'license.png');

    message.channel.send(attachment);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not `require('@img')`, this will try to make your image's content read as text be part of the script.

Instead let node-canvas's `loadImage` handle the fetching of that resource: make `licenseTemp` be the URL to that image directly.